# an if statement returns true, but the condition won't trigger

Tags: javascript, animation

I have an if statement in my code as you can see below. When I check in console log when those two elements collide with each other, the if statement becomes true, but it won't stop my interval function. I wonder what would have caused it to not work as it should?

```
var animationTimer = setInterval(bladAnimation, 30);

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        // <--
        fx = -15;
        fy = 0;
        froskAnimation()
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        // opp
        fy = -15;
        fx = 0;
        froskAnimation()
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        // -->
        fx = 15;
        fy = 0;
        froskAnimation()
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        // ned
        fy = 15;
        fx = 0;
        froskAnimation()
    }
}

function froskAnimation() {

    Xfrosk = fx + Xfrosk;
    Yfrosk = fy + Yfrosk;

    if ((Yfrosk + 70 > maxY) || (Yfrosk < minY)) {
        Yfrosk = Yfrosk - fy;
    }
    if ((Xfrosk + 70 > maxX) || (Xfrosk < minX)) {
        Xfrosk = Xfrosk - fx;
    }

    frosk.style.left = Xfrosk + "px";
    frosk.style.top = Yfrosk + "px";
    console.log(Xfrosk)
}

function bladAnimation() {
    Yblad = by + Yblad;

    if ((Yblad + 70 > maxY) || (Yblad < minY)) {
        by = by * -1;
    }

    blad.style.top = Yblad + "px";
}

if (blad.x < frosk.x + frosk.width  && blad.x + blad.width  > frosk.x 
        && blad.y < frosk.y + frosk.height && blad.y + blad.height > frosk.y) {
    clearInterval(animationTimer);
}
```

full code here: https://codepen.io/ctrlvi/pen/jXbJYG

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh my , my codepen didn't save it.. i copied and pasted it into the link now. thank you for telling me

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have added extra codes. Is this enough to answer my question?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: I moved that comment to an answer. If it did work please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That condition is executed only once, when your javascript is loaded. At that point the condition is probably false. You should move it at the end of bladAnimation (I suppose what you're trying to do is stop the self-moving block when it hits the other one).

```
function bladAnimation() {
    Yblad = by + Yblad;

    if ((Yblad + 70 > maxY) || (Yblad < minY)) {
        by = by * -1;
    }

    blad.style.top = Yblad + "px";

    if (blad.x < frosk.x + frosk.width  && blad.x + blad.width  > frosk.x 
        && blad.y < frosk.y + frosk.height && blad.y + blad.height > frosk.y) {
        clearInterval(animationTimer);
    }

}
```